# AWS Permissions no longer work after consolidated billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

So we have this aws account with some permissions and it was working fine at first. We were able to deploy to aws using serverless framework. But then the client decided to setup an organization since they have other aws accounts also and to consolidate the billing under 1 account, they added the account they gave us to the organization. Now the problem is when we deployed using serverless again, serverless can no longer see the deployment bucket with an access denied error. But when the account was removed from the organization, serverless is able to locate the bucket. Is there some addition permissions or changes to the permissions that needs to be done when an account is linked to an organization? Can someone explain to me cause I can't seem to find any example of my scenario in a google search. I am new to AWS and this is the first time I experience organzations in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

The only implication to permissions from joining an OU (organization unit) would be via the Service Contol Policy (SCP). Verify that the SCP attached to the organization does not block the actions you are attempting to execute.

Answer (score 0):

We would love to get more information if possible, but I would maybe start looking in the following places in your consolidated account:

- Trusted access for AWS services - https://console.aws.amazon.com/organizations/home?#/organization/settings
- https://console.aws.amazon.com/organizations/home?#/policies

See if anything was changed there, if someone added a policy, or if the AWS Resource Access Manager is disabled.